# Why does it return 0?

Tags: java

The following code is a recursion example which returns how many numbers between 0 and 9 (including 9) are in the given `String` argument:

```
public int sayiAdediBul(String str){
  int holder = 0;

  if (sayi == 9) { //base case
    for (int a = 0; a < str.length(); a++) {
      if(Integer.parseInt(str.substring(a,a+1)) == sayi) { // im increasing sayi int variable everytime calling the method 
        holder++; 
      }
    }

    System.out.print(sayi + " :");
    return holder; // here, holder returns 0 , isnt it supposed to return how many 9 there are
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no recursion in this code. And `sayi` isn't declared— is it 9 or isn't it?

Comment: Your function seems to miss an else block, is this intentional?

Comment: Please create a proper [mcve], the `sayi` is missing and the method is not completely shown.

Comment: please rectify your piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really bad. I help you a little..

```
 if(Integer.parseInt(str.substring(a,a+1)) == sayi) ...
```

in your case is this false.

> The variable holder is initialized with 0. The variable holder dont
>   make +1 because dont get in the if statement. The variable holder is
>   0. The variable holder returns.